# Suggestion needed: how to create a global Menu bar using C# (WPF/WinForms)?

Tags: c#

So, I want to create a "floating" menubar (without a window). How is that accomplish in C#?

Also, if you could drop some pointers on:

- How to make that bar "listen" global key shortcuts would be greatly appreciated.
- When another window is maximized, don't allow such window to maximize on top of my toolbar.

The reason for this is that, I want to show my manager the concept of the Mile High (Mac-like) menu bar.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really like the concept (I've seen it done from time to time), but...

You would create a mode-less form with the FormBorderStyle set to none.  Then put your menus on that form.

You will also have some work ahead of you to figure out the screen resolution, but that can be easily googled.  Also, after a menu is clicked to will need to communicate to a command class of some sort to tell the rest of the application what was just requested.

The rest of what you are looking for involves a lot of PInvoke'ing, and I usually don't go there if I don't have to.